# How to use Machine Learning model in objective-C with CoreML

Tags: objective-c, xcode, machine-learning, coreml

I have Machine Vision project made in objective-C (a couple of thousands of lines). To complete it I need to import my machine My_model.mlmodel with the latest coreML library. (as digression My_model.mlmodel was created in Python with coremltools )
I am trying to instantiate it, but nothing works I couldn't find any tutorials or helps on this topic.  Of course, I imported my model to the pure Swift project, and it works.
So I attached Swift class to my project hoping to make it work this way, but here again, Xcode translate the model to "Objective-C generated interface for model" and the model is not visible in Swift class.

Below picture shows that Xcode automatically imports .mlmodel as Objective-C class.

[image: Xcode imports mlmodel as Objective-C class]

I need to put vector in the model and get the response.

Please help me; I am stacked a couple of lines from completing this project. 
How to use My_model.mlmodel inside of Objective-C
Is there any work around or maybe straight easy way like in Swift

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you click on the little arrow next to linear_model (where it says "Objective-C generated interface for model"), then Xcode will show you what this Obj-C code looks like.

Comment: I did. I tried to pull this option, but I am doing something wrong. The model even gets to my code but I can not figure out how to put data in or out. If I put it in my code, the compiler issues warning: 
"expression result unused"

Comment: Do you maybe have any example in Objective-C? I tried to instantiate the model with all possible combinations found at apple documentation website. The Swift version is much simpler, but the project is too big to translate it to Swift. I tried to do it through Swift code inside of my project but Xcode automatically transforms model to Objective-C, so I am back to square one.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way that worked for me using my own image recognition model:

```
#import <CoreML/CoreML.h>
#import <Vision/Vision.h>
#import "Your_Model_Here.h"    

- (void)readModelMLObjc{

            MLModel *model;
            VNCoreMLModel *m;
            VNCoreMLRequest *request;
            model = [[[Your_Model_Here alloc] init] model];

            m = [VNCoreMLModel modelForMLModel: model error:nil];
            request = [[VNCoreMLRequest alloc] initWithModel: m completionHandler: (VNRequestCompletionHandler) ^(VNRequest *request, NSError *error){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    NSInteger numberOfResults = request.results.count;
                    NSArray *results = [request.results copy];
                    VNClassificationObservation *topResult = ((VNClassificationObservation *)(results[0]));
                    NSString *messageLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f: %@", topResult.confidence, topResult.identifier];
                    NSLog(@"%@", messageLabel);

                });
            }];

            request.imageCropAndScaleOption = VNImageCropAndScaleOptionCenterCrop;


            CIImage *coreGraphicsImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:image];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0), ^{
                VNImageRequestHandler *handler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc] initWithCIImage:coreGraphicsImage  options:@{}];
                [handler performRequests:@[request] error:nil];
            });}

        }
```

I hope I've helped ;)

Comment: god bless you haha

Comment: All of us!! hehe

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, this project on obj-c will help you:
https://github.com/freedomtan/SimpleInceptionV3-ObjC/tree/continuous-mobilenet/SimpleInceptionV3-ObjC

In my project I use this method to init my model

```
#import "my_model.h"

@property (nonatomic, strong) my_model *model;

- (void)configureModel {
    NSURL *modelUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"my_model" withExtension:@"mlmodelc"];
    NSError *error;
    self.model = [[my_model alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelUrl error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"cover search error: model not configure");
    }
}
```

Some explanations about why "mlmodelc": 
https://blog.zedge.net/developers-blog/hotswapping-machine-learning-models-in-coreml-for-iphone

Comment: HI, Alex while I'm trying to use with chosen image its crashing 2019-08-09 23:22:24.460166+0600 SimpleInceptionV3-ObjC[8806:452968] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-08-09 23:22:24.460404+0600 SimpleInceptionV3-ObjC[8806:452968] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings. Can you tell why it's crashing?